# what should be in a MVC view

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

Is the below considered too much for a view in codeigniter / php? where $springtrail is an array calculated in a model?

```
<div id="page_name">Website</div>
<?php
$count = count($springtrail);
for($i = $count; $i >= 1; $i--){
    if ($i != 1)
    {
        ?> <div class="springtrail_button" id="st-0">arrayitem</div> <?php
    } else
    {
        ?> <a class="springtrail_link" href="#" id="1">Add</a> <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I think it's okay for your view to contain whatever logic necessary for presenting the data however you require. Anyway, Codeigniter allows for a great deal of flexibilty, it does not impose rules. Your inclusion of loops and conditional logic in the view certainly won't break anything, it's left to your judgement ultimately.

Comment: A view, in a real MVC would be an instance, which contains UI logic, juggles multiple templates and is able to request data, that it needs, from model layer. But CI does MVC just like religions do morals.

Comment: Thanks.  Wasn't sure if standards were more strictly enforced.  And yes ...logic, sorry for being general

Comment: Why is this getting voted to close? Seems like a pretty clear-cut question to me, with a pretty clear-cut answer.

Comment: @JasonSwett, I think it doesn't fit the SO standard, it's mostly up to coder preference at this point. It also has [some dups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698880/mvc-how-much-code-should-be-in-a-view?rq=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it has to do with your appearance logic, so putting it outside your view would in essence remove logic from your view (and put it elsewhere), breaking your mvc model

Answer (score 1):

I think it's ok, as long as you don't extend to much.

But, it would be better to keep that logic inside the controller... therefor you could do something like so:

Controller:

```
$count = count($springtrail);
for($i = $count; $i >= 1; $i--) {
    $data['s_count'] = ($i !== 1 ? 'button' : 'link');
}
```

View:

```
<?php if($s_count == 'button'): ?>
   <html here>
<?php else: ?>
   <other html here>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would say that is too much logic. I think I might do something like this instead:

```
<div id="page_name">Website</div>

<a class="springtrail_link" href="#" id="1">Add</a>

<?php foreach ($springtrail as $item): ?>
  <div class="springtrail_button" id="st-0">arrayitem</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Notice how the syntax is different. I'd strongly recommend using the [alternative PHP syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

I think anytime you find yourself assigning variable values in a view, that's a sign that you're headed down the wrong path. And as for displaying the first item in the list differently, well, if the first item is different from the rest, then I'd say it's not  really a member of that list, right? Make it a separate value in the controller. It doesn't look like you're even outputting a variable value for that first item, though, so why not just display it statically before you start outputting the list?

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was going to go this route at first, but the array will have a dynamic count, and I wanted to position the "add" link at the end of it everytime it updates, whether it has a count of 1 or 10.